# How to create a border gap illusion

Tags: html, css, svg, border

This is the illusion that I am attempting to create:

[image]

Notice that my designer wants the border cut off in the middle of the div, *this* is what I need to know how to do. I don't think overlapping with a z-index will work because of how the HTML is laid out.

This is the HTML code of which the structure may not be changed for maximum device compatibility, however, if adding an element is the solution, I believe that may be done:

```
<div id="nav_icons_con" class="mopn">
  <div id="inner_nav_container" class="show_inner_nav">
    <div class="nav_link_container">Home</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the basic current CSS code:

```
#nav_icons_con {
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 5.005em;
    width: 5.005em;background-image:url(background.png);
    background-size:70%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:.385em .385em 0 0;
}
#nav_icons_con.mopn{
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:2px solid #83C5E6;
    border-bottom:none;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #666;
}
#inner_nav_container, .inner_nav_container{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:5.39em;
    right:.385em;
    width:12.5em;
    white-space:normal;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:2px solid #83C5E6;
    border-top:none;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #666;
}
#inner_nav_container.show_inner_nav, .inner_nav_container.show_inner_nav{display:block;}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question...  which part are you talking about?  The blue border being cut off on the bottom of the icon?  Can you throw your code into a jsfiddle so we can see it how you are seeing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to position the tab element over the sub element, so as to cover up that section of the border. However, the use of `box-shadow` complicates this.

One way is to add another element inside the root element, so that the root element can still cast the shadow, but the element inside is positioned above. See my code below, for a basic example.

### Working Example:

```css
.icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    /*Create the shape for the shadow.*/
    border: 5px solid #83C5E6;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #666;
}
.icon-content {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    /*Move back over the border.*/
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    /*Make tall enough to cover the top border.*/
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    /*Add border, except on the bottom.*/
    border: 5px solid #83C5E6;
    border-bottom: 0;
    /*Position up a layer.*/
    z-index: 1;
}
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #83C5E6;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    <div class="icon-content">
        
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="item">Home</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did work, thank you. I'm curious as to how the use of box-shadow complicated the former solution, though. It was a solution I tried before & it didn't work, I figured it was due to fact that I was trying to make the child overlap the parent.

Comment: @CrystalMiller If the smaller box were simply positioned above the larger box, it would cast the shadow on the larger box, rather then beneath.

Comment: True, but because the smaller box is the parent of the larger box I don't think that can be done. At least, I don't see how it could be done. It defies the laws of z-index that I am familiar with.